# Change event for textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a task where I should be able to put any text in `<textarea>`, then text will be immediately displayed in `<p>`. I am trying to do it with `addEventListener` that works fine with input field but for some reasons doesn't work for textarea.

```
let textArea = document.querySelector('.text-area')

let output = document.querySelector('.p-tag')

textArea.addEventListener('change', updateValue)

function updateValue(e){
    output.textContent = e.target.value
}
```

Comment: You can use the "onkeyup" event instead.

Comment: so use a keyUp event listener instead

Comment: Use the `input` event instead of `keyup` or `change` for better compatibility with touch devices that don't have "keys".

Comment: In what way does this work with an input field but not with a textarea? The behavior is identical with the code you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event instead:

> **Note:** The `input` event is fired every time the `value` of the element changes. This is unlike the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

From [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event):

> Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the `change` event fires at a different moment:
>
> - […]
> - When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g., after editing the value of [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) or [`<input type="text">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)).